# Wordpress JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have enqueued my js file in WP which shows up in the page source as:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/yhomh/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/js/menu.js?ver=3.9.2"></script>`

The js code is supposed apply the class "first-half" to the first half of all `<li>` elements under `<ul id="menu-main">`. The code I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var menuItems = $("ul#menu-main li");

    menuItems = menuItems.slice(0, Math.floor(menuItems.length/2)).addClass("first-half");

});
```

The code does not work. Please help me find where I made a mistake. As a beginner to jquery, I would appreciate any help possible, thanks!

Comment: Check whether jquery is loaded or not. Go to console and type `!!window.jQuery;` If it returns true, then jQuery is enabled and if false, then it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default, so you'll need a no-conflict wrapper, as described in the [**codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // code here

});
```

and make sure jQuery is  added as a dependency

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'handle', '/url/menu.js', array('jquery'), '3.9.2', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your jQuery library is loaded perfectly. You can check it in [Developer tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). You can check for error in console.

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

use jQuery [no-conflict wrapper](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace '$' with 'jQuery'.

Some times $ sign not worked so you have to use jQuery keyword like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var menuItems = jQuery("ul#menu-main li");

    menuItems = menuItems.slice(0, Math.floor(menuItems.length/2)).addClass("first-half");

});
```

Try it.